# datos actualizados de label se muestran fuera de la raiz o el Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

estoy tratando de realizar un GUI para monitorear las latencias de servidores DNS, sin embargo al ejecutar el código al cabo de unos minutos, los label's configurados dejan de actualizarse y es como si el GUI se congelara, sin embargo por medio de un botón observo que no esta congelado, pero observo también que me aparece una etiqueta en la parte superior izquierda de mi monitor fuera del GUI donde veo que si cambian los datos (adjunto imagen) por lo cual no entiendo que puede estar pasando. el proceso de realizar la prueba de ping la separe en un hilo independiente para que no bloqueara el GUI, pero al cabo de unos minutos de funcionamiento no veo mas datos actualizados en el GUI.

adjunto el código, y muchas gracias de antemano

```
    import time
    import threading
    import logging
    from tkinter import *
    from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
    
    logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] - %(threadName)-10s : %(message)s')
    
    #------------------------ definicion de root -----------------------------
    root = Tk()
    root.title("latencia DNS")
    root.resizable(1,1)
    root.iconbitmap("F:\Trabajo\proyectos\Latencia DNS\claro.ico")
    
    #----------------------- definicion del Frame -----------------------------
    miFrame=Frame(root, width=700, height=500)
    miFrame.pack()
    miFrame.config(bg="white")
    miImagen = PhotoImage(file="F:\Trabajo\proyectos\Latencia DNS\logo.png")  # se agrega logo
    Label(miFrame, image=miImagen).grid(row=0,column = 0)
    
    miLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "LATENCIA DNS",bg="white",fg="red",font=("Comic Sans MS",20))
    miLabel.grid(row=0,column = 2)
    
    #----------------------- Se realizan los pines a los Dns -----------------------------
    dns = ["8.8.8.8" , "190.157.8.38" , "190.157.8.109" , "190.157.8.100" , "190.157.8.108" , "190.157.8.6" , "190.157.8.33" , "190.157.8.1" , "190.157.8.42" , "190.157.8.10" , "190.157.8.46", "190.157.8.101"]
    tiempo = [0]*12
    resultado = ["null"]*12
    tiempomax = [0]*12
    ciclo = 0
    
    dnstLable = Label(miFrame,text="DNS ",fg = "red", bg = "white", font=("Comic Sans MS",15))
    dnstLable.grid(row=1,column = 1)
    tLable = Label(miFrame,text="TIEMPO (ms) ",fg = "red", bg = "white", font=("Comic Sans MS",15))
    tLable.grid(row=1,column = 2)
    tmax = Label(miFrame, text = "Tmax (ms)", fg = "red", bg = "white", font=("Comic Sans MS",15))
    tmax.grid(row=1, column = 3) 
    
    dnsLable = Label(miFrame,text="DNS ", bg ="red", relief = RAISED, width=20)
    dnsLable.grid(row=2,column = 1, pady = 5)
    tiempoLabel = Label(miFrame, text = " ", bg = "red" , fg ="white", relief = RAISED, width=5)
    tiempoLabel.grid(row=2, column = 2 , pady = 5)
    
    def borrar():
        global tiempomax
        tiempomax = [0]*12
    
    def actualiza():
        i = 0
        logging.debug('inicio')
        for i in range (12):
            resultado[i] = str(tiempo[i])
            if resultado[i] == "None":
                Label(miFrame,text="DNS " + dns[i], bg ="red", relief = RAISED, width=20).grid(row=i+2,column = 1, pady = 5)
                Label(miFrame, text = "Loss", bg = "red" , fg ="white", relief = RAISED, width=5).grid(row=i+2, column = 2 , pady = 5)
            else:
                if int(tiempo[i]*1000) > tiempomax[i]:
                    tiempomax[i] = int(tiempo[i]*1000)
                    Label(miFrame, text = str(int(tiempomax[i])) + " ms", bg ="white", width=5).grid(row=i+2, column = 3, pady = 5) 
                    
                    if tiempomax[i] > 90:
                        tiempomax[i] = int(tiempo[i]*1000)
                        Label(miFrame, text = str(int(tiempomax[i])) + " ms", bg = "red" ,fg ="white", relief = RAISED, width=5).grid(row=i+2, column = 3, pady = 5)
                    
                if int(tiempo[i]*1000) >= 70:
                    Label(miFrame,text="DNS " + dns[i],bg ="red", relief = RAISED, width=20).grid(row=i+2,column = 1, sticky="w", pady = 5)
                    Label(miFrame, text = str(int(tiempo[i]*1000)) + " ms", fg ="red", relief = RAISED, width=5).grid(row=i+2, column = 2, pady = 5)
                        
                else:
                    Label(miFrame,text="DNS " + dns[i],bg ="white", width=20).grid(row=i+2,column = 1, sticky="w", pady = 5)
                    Label(miFrame, text = str(int(tiempo[i]*1000)) + " ms", bg ="white", width=5).grid(row=i+2, column = 2, pady = 5) 
        #root.after(2000, actualiza)
        logging.debug('FIN')
    
    def ejecuta_ping():
        global tiempo
        i = 0 
        for i in range(12):
            tiempo[i] = ping(dns[i], timeout = 0.5)
        actualiza()
        root.after(2000,ejecuta_ping)
    
    hilo = threading.Thread(target=ejecuta_ping)
    hilo.start()[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
    
    logging.debug('termina')
    
    boton_borrar = Button(miFrame, text = "clear", command = borrar)
    boton_borrar.grid(row=14, column = 3)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: imagen del problema]

Comment: Lo veo un poco desordenado, pero dandole una vista rápida, te recomiendo un par de cosas: 1. No necesitas usar threading, solo pon `root.after(0, ejecuta_ping)` antes del mainloop. 2. Usa textvariables!!!! Sino estás creando Label tras Label encima del otro, y la memoria se te va a llenar, y va a llevar a otras complicaciones. 3. Si no vas a usar textvariables, por lo menos limpia los labels antes de recrearlos. Puedes meterlos en otro frame y luego hacer `for child in frame.winfo_children(): child.destroy()`